# Scrape for exact matches while scraping Google results

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-search

I'm scraping google search results using this code:

```py
from googlesearch import search   

query = "water outage site:https://www.heraldsun.com/"

for j in search(query, tld="com", num=100, stop=None, pause=2):
    print(j)
```

This currently gives me results for articles that have the word 'water' in them as well as those that have 'outage' in them, but I'm looking for articles that contain the phrase 'water outage' - in a google search, this would be akin to searching for "water outage". I tried this:

```
query= "\"water outage\" site:https://www.heraldsun.com/"
```

However, I still see the same number of results. Is there a way to get exact matches?

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries.  Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to slightly change the search query:

```py
# from this
query = "water outage site:https://www.heraldsun.com/"

# to this (removing https part and backslashes)
query = "water outage site:heraldsun.com"
```

So your code would look like this:

```py
from googlesearch import search   

query = "water outage site:heraldsun.com"

for j in search(query, tld="com", num=100, stop=None, pause=2):
    print(j)
```

---

Alternatively, if you need to parse Google or other search engines, you can try to use [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/playground). It's a paid API with a free plan that currently parses data from seven search engines and search engines from marketplaces such as Walmart, AppStore, and more.

Example code to parse the same thing as you were trying to do:

```py
import os, json
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "water outage site:heraldsun.com",
    "hl": "en",                               # language
    "gl": "us",                               # country to search from
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")           # your API key
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# prints full JSON response from the first page
for result in results["organic_results"]:
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))  
    
    # want a title and a link?
    # print(result['title'])
    # print(result['link'])


# part of the output
'''
{
  "position": 1,
  "title": "Water out in parts of Hillsborough after contractor ruptures main",
  "link": "https://amp.heraldsun.com/news/local/counties/orange-county/article233990732.html",
  "displayed_link": "https://amp.heraldsun.com \u203a counties \u203a article233990732",
  "date": "Aug 14, 2019",
  "snippet": "A water main break Wednesday morning has left some Hillsborough water customers without service. A contractor installing communications ...",
  "about_this_result": {
    "source": {
      "description": "The Herald-Sun is an American, English language daily newspaper in Durham, North Carolina, published by the McClatchy Company.",
      "source_info_link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Herald-Sun_(Durham,_North_Carolina)",
      "security": "secure",
      "icon": "https://serpapi.com/searches/61922a67c7ad41c5dfd89667/images/2a749afb909e95f5dfd0a23ae293037290151a6162f1bfcd35e02e2733abee61f2ede2c6f00c6c9c5e8cd5c2fcb2f610.png"
    },
    "keywords": [
      "water",
      "outage"
    ],
    "related_keywords": [
      "main break"
    ],
    "languages": [
      "English"
    ],
    "regions": [
      "the United States"
    ]
  },
  "cached_page_link": null
}
# other results..
'''
```

> Dislaimer, I work for SerpApi.